# Add extra button on woocommerce shop page and use it to send the product info including image in a mail

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

1. I want to add an extra button after "add to cart".
2. It will open a form with only the email field.
3. After submitting an email id, it will send product name, image, description to that email id.

Here is the graphical representation of the above problem:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can hook a action that would add the button after add to cart. You can achieve this by pasting the code below in functions.php file

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'send_via_email_btn' );
function send_via_email_btn(){
   $btn = '<div class="btn-wrap"><a href="Javascript:void(0)" 
   onclick="openpopup">Send Via Email</a></div>';
   echo $btn;
}
```

Next you need to create a form where you will have hidden input fields that will post along with email id. You can add this popup form in your footer.php file

```
<form action="index.php">
   <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="email">
   <input type="hidden" name="post_title" value="<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>">
   <input type="hidden" name="post_content" value="<?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>">
   <input type="hidden" name="post_image" value="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>">
   <input type="hidden" name="form_type" value="mailp_info">
   <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>

if(isset($_POST['form_type']) && !empty($_POST['form_type']) && $_POST['form_type'] == "mail_info") {
  $post_title = $_POST['post_title'];
  $shortcontent = $_POST['post_content'];
  $img = $_POST['post_image'];

 $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8','From: My Site Name &lt;support@example.com');
 $to = 'emailsendto@example.com';
 $subject = 'Product Info';
 $body = 'Product Name: '.$post_title.'<br>Product Description: '.$shortcontent;
 $attachments = array( $img );

 wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers, $attachments );
}
```

I hope this works for you. Let me know if any questions

Comment: Thanks...the code is working...I put the form code in modal and called it from the button....thanks a lot